# Eigengap of $SS^T$ vs. $\frac{1}{2}(SS + S^TS^T)$, where S is doubly stochastic & irreducible

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, means

Suppose $S$ is doubly stochastic irreducible matrix, and consider the two matrices $G=SS^T$ and $A=\frac{1}{2}(SS+S^TS^T)$. Note that in some sense $G$ is the "geometric mean" of $SS$ and $S^TS^T$, while $A$ is the arithmetic mean.

Both $G$ and $A$ are symmetric, doubly stochastic and irreducible, and thus have dominant eigenvalue $1$ relative to the eigenvector $1$ (the eigenvector with all components equal to $1$). I am interested in the *second* largest eigenvalue, and in particular in understanding whether I can say anything about whether it's larger in $G$ or in $A$.

Note that applying Rayleigh's principle, we can write the second eigenvalue of a symmetric irreducible double stochastic matrix $M$ as $\sup_{x:~1^Tx=0} \frac{x^TMx}{x^Tx}$ (we are taking the sup over all vectors x that are orthogonal to the dominant eigenvector). Perhaps some generalization of the geometric-arithmetic mean inequality can be brought into play to prove that the second largest eigenvalue of $A$ is never smaller than that of $G$?

Comment: The "AM-GM inequality" in this case reads that $SS + S^TS^T \ge S^T S + SS^T$ (meaning that the difference of the lhs and the rhs is non-negative definite), which in particular implies that the second eigenvalue of $SS + S^TS^T$ is at least that of $S^T S + SS^T$. Concerning your question, I believe that in some cases, the second eigenvalue of $A$ is larger, in others, that of $G$. Anyway, did you try to check this numerically at least for $3\times 3$ matrices?

Comment: @zhoraster Let me see if I understand you correctly. Are you stating that the second eigenvalue of $(SS + S^TS^T)$ equals or exceeds that of $(S^T S + SS^T)$? Because that seems really what I was hoping for: unless I am missing something, $(SS + S^TS^T)=2A$, and  $S^T S + SS^T=2SS^T=2G$ (note that $SS^T=S^TS$ being symmetric). Could you write down the proof, or at least provide a pointer? I tried looking for "AM-GM inequality" for matrices, but I just cannot manage to sift through all the material efficiently.

Comment: @Anonymous: Why is $SS^T=S^TS$? You're not assuming that $S$ is symmetric, are you?

Comment: @joriki Ah, you are right, sorry. Having what I had hoped for in sight blinded me. $SS^T$ is symmetric, but $S$ is not, in general. Still, it would be nice to have a pointer to the AM-GM inequality for matrices!

Comment: @zhoraster: The inequality actually holds in the other direction, as you can see by expanding $\|Sx-S^\top x\|^2\ge0$.

Comment: (Or, more immediately, $(S-S^\top)^\top(S-S^\top)\ge0$.)

Comment: @joriki, you're right, I confused the sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll prove that the second largest eigenvalue of $G$ is not less than that of $A$. This is quite easy and almost proved in the comments.

Since $x^T(S^T - S)^T(S^T - S)x = ||(S^T-S)x||^2$ for all $x$, we have
$$
x^T(S^T S + SS^T)x \ge x^T(S S + S^T S^T)x = 2x^T A x.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
\sup_{x: 1^T x = 0, ||x||=1}  x^T(S^T S + SS^T)x \ge 2\sup_{x: 1^T x = 0, ||x||=1} x^TAx.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\sup_{x: 1^T x = 0, ||x||=1}  x^T(S^T S + SS^T)x\le \sup_{x: 1^T x = 0, ||x||=1}  x^TS^T Sx + \sup_{x: 1^T x = 0, ||x||=1}  x^TS S^Tx.
$$
The right-hand side is the sum of second largest eigenvalues of $SS^T$ and $S^TS$. But the latter are equal, which implies the claim.

Similarly it can be shown that the sum of first $k$ largest eigenvalues of $G$ is not less than that of $A$ for any $k\ge 1$ and any, not necessarily doubly stochastic, matrix $S$. The proof is based on this generalization of Rayleigh principle: for a symmetric matrix $M$ the sum of $k$ largest eigenvalues is
$$
\sup_{\text{ONS }x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k} \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^T M x_i,
$$
where ONS stands for "orthonormal system".